# How to send email when SPECIFIC scheduled task fails to run

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, scheduler, taskscheduler

I have a exe file that is executed every day by the Task Scheduler on my Windows 2008. If that script should fail to start, or if the script fails during execution, I would like to get an email notification.
There are many examples of getting Task Schedular to send an email based on an event log entry. However, I only want to be notified if MY particular scheduled task fails, not get a notification for all tasks that fails with an EventID 203/103/201. How can I do that without any custom software?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new Task that runs this PowerShell Script.

```
$ScheduledTaskName = "Taskname"
$Result = (schtasks /query /FO LIST /V /TN $ScheduledTaskName  | findstr "Result")
$Result = $Result.substring(12)
$Code = $Result.trim()

If ($Code -gt 0) {
    $User = "admin@company.com"
    $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $User, $Pass


$From = "Alert Scheduled Task <task@servername>"
$To = "Admin <admin@company.com>"
$Subject = "Scheduled task 'Taskname' failed on SRV-001"
$Body = "Error code: $Code"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.company.com"
$SMTPPort = "25"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential $Cred
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to this post just in case someone has a similar challenge on later server o/s. There is now a PowerShell cmdlet to get Scheduled Task information.

```
$ScheduledTaskName = 'Taskname'
(Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName $ScheduledTaskName).LastTaskResult
```